# How can I control my Twisted-based Python IRC bot interactively?

Tags: python, twisted, bots, irc, command-line-interface

So I've got the beginnings of a pretty basic IRC bot, using Twisted's IRC client:

http://pastebin.com/jjMSM64n

How would I go about hooking into the bot/factory/reactor so I could control the bot via the command line?

So when the bot is ran via CLI, it starts up as usual but drops you into a wee custom interactive prompt. I think this CLI/message loop would have to be where reactor.run() is though.. and I'm not sure how that would all work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One way would be using Twisted Conch over stdio (http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.conch.stdio.html). If you want to log into your bot remotely via SSH, and into a Python interactive shell (where you can access any internals of your bot), have a look at Twisted Manhole.

Comment: You can try `python -m twisted.conch.stdio` and just launch your bot via importing a Python function :).

Comment: So I can run the bot via the REPL from running "python -m twisted.conch.stdio". Aside from getting a "ReactorAlreadyRunning" error, I don't see how this lets me interact with the reactor object?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to use the [twisted.internet.stdio.StandardIO](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.stdio.StandardIO.html).

Look at the [examples](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/):

- [stdin.py](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/stdin.py) - reading a line at a time from standard input without blocking the reactor
- [stdiodemo.py](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/stdiodemo.py) - example using stdio, Deferreds, LineReceiver and twisted.web.client.